# How to get table data from Wikipedia with API

Tags: api, wikipedia

How should I structure my query to get the data from the (first) table in the section *Mixed martial arts record* from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Bisping? Ideally I'd like to get the table data as json but HTML will work too.

I've tried this query to get the sections of the page: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=sections&page=Michael_Bisping

The result tells me that the table is in the section with index 12. I don't know what query I should run next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use there [API Sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=Michael%20Bisping&prop=text%7Clanglinks%7Ccategories%7Clinks%7Ctemplates%7Cimages%7Cexternallinks%7Crevid%7Cdisplaytitle%7Ciwlinks%7Cproperties%7Cparsewarnings&section=12&callback=) to generate an url!

Set `action` to `parse`.

`Page` to `Michael Bisping`

`Section` to `12` (Mixed martial arts record)

Final url:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=Michael%20Bisping&prop=text&section=12&callback=
```

---

I've used `prop=extracts` with `action=query` to get parsed result:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Michael%20Bisping&prop=extracts
```

However, this request is not possible (?) with `section=12`, maybe there is another way of paring the result

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to only get the table of the section? Is it possible to get the HTML without style attributes?

Comment: Yea, I've used `prop=extracts` to get a parsed result, but for some reason it's not working on this request, I'm stil trying ;)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the whole section with this query: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Michael_Bisping&section=12

I'm targeting the specific section by querying its index (12 in this case).

Comment: Damn, just to slow ;) Tip; use the [API Sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=Michael%20Bisping&prop=text%7Clanglinks%7Ccategories%7Clinks%7Ctemplates%7Cimages%7Cexternallinks%7Crevid%7Cdisplaytitle%7Ciwlinks%7Cproperties%7Cparsewarnings&section=12&callback=)